# Is it possible to use Sphinx search with dynamic conditions?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, ultrasphinx

In my web app I need to perform 3 types of searching on `items` table with the following conditions:

1. `items.is_public = 1` (use `title` field for indexing) - a lot of results can be retrieved(cardinality is much higher than in other cases)
2. `items.category_id = {X}` (use `title` + `private_notes` fields for indexing) - usually less than 100 results
3. `items.user_id = {X}` (use `title` + `private_notes` fields for indexing) - usually less than 100 results

I can't find a way to make Sphinx work in all these cases, but it works well in 1st case.
Should I use Sphinx just for the 1st case and use plain old "slow" FULLTEXT searching in MySQL(at least because of lower cardinality in 2-3 cases)?

Or is it just me and Sphinx can do pretty much everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without full knowledge of your models I might be missing something, but how's this:

```
class item < ActiveRecord::Base
  define_index do
    indexes :title
    indexes :private_notes
    has :is_public, :type => :boolean
    has :category_id
    has :user_id
  end
end
```

1)

```
Item.search(:conditions => {:title => "blah"}, :with => {:is_public => true})
```

2)

```
Item.search("blah", :with => {:category_id => 1})
```

3)

```
Item.search("blah", :with => {:user_id => 196})
```

Comment: Thanks! I find thinking_sphinx much more powerful than Ultrasphinx gem. So there's no need to switchback to non-sphinx FULLTEXT search now.